# Python - Error when merging multiple files and then delete the source file

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, shutil

I am trying to merge a set of files from a folder into one file and then delete all the files apart from the merged file.

I get an error

```
shutil.SameFileError: '/Users/user/folder/.DS_Store' and '/Users/user/folder/.DS_Store' are the same file
```

Given below is the code I am using:

base = path where the files are extracted to
base2 = sub-folder within 'base' folder

```
allFiles = glob.glob(base2 + "/*")
    list_ = []
    for file_ in allFiles:
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=None, sep = ',', engine = 'python')
            list_.append(df)
        except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
            continue
    # Deleting all files except the concatenated file by day
    os.system("cd /{}/{}/{}/{};find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size 0 -delete".format(base,
            file_type, parent, child))
    updatedfiles = glob.glob(base2 + "/*")
    try:
        df_v1 = [pd.read_csv(fp, sep=',').assign(FileName=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in updatedfiles]
        df = pd.concat(df_v1, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
        df.to_csv(base2 + "/{}_{}.csv".format(date, parent), index=False)
    except Exception as e:

    # Merging final output file
    file_from = "{}/{}/{}".format(base, parent, child)
    file_to = "{}/{}/{}".format(base, parent, child)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk((os.path.normpath(file_from)), topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            SourceFolder = os.path.join(root, name)
            shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, file_to) <<-- Error is thrown at this line
    # Deleting any sub-folders within the folder
    if os.path.exists(filename) and not os.path.isdir(filename) and not os.path.islink(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
    updatedfiles_1 = glob.glob(file_from + "/*")
    try:
        df_v0 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in updatedfiles_1], sort=True)
        df_v0.to_csv('{}/{}_{}'.format(final_files, parent, child), index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        df_v0.to_csv('{}/{}_{}'.format(final_files, parent, child), index=False)
```

Could anyone guide me where am I going wrong with the above code. Thanks

Comment: In your code, `file_from` and `file_to` are the SAME.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mad Lee mentioned the SourceFolder and file_to are same, you need to make a check that both files are not same.
Put this line before the line that is throwing an error.

if SourceFolder!=file_to:
    shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, file_to)